# Display QList contents

Tags: c++, qt

I want to display the contents of a `QList` just like how it is displayed in the console with `qDebug()`

For example:

```
QList<QNetworkCookie>  cookies = mManager->cookieJar()->cookiesForUrl(mUrl);
qDebug() << "COOKIES for" << mUrl.host() << cookies;
```

Output:

```
QNetworkCookie("MSession=kr6i819jbvkorherbe76oh23c7; domain=website.com; path=/)"
```

Is there a function that I can use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a `QDebug` object that will store anything streamed into it, inside a string. Here is it:

```
QString str;
QDebug dStream(&str);

dStream << mUrl.host();
```

Now you can put `str` wherever you want. For example a `QTextBrowser`:

```
ui->textBrowser->insertPlainText(str);
```

This should work everywhere that `qDebug()` works. Because `qDebug()` itself returns a `QDebug` object according to [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QDebug.html) documentation.